# Delphi Compiler Warning: Unit 'ExceptionLog' is deprecated

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I am using EurekaLog 7 Professional in my Delphi application. While migrating from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE4, I am getting the following compiler warning.

```
[dcc32 Warning] myproject.dpr(4): W1006 Unit 'ExceptionLog' is deprecated
```

How should I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to such questions is always that you need to remove references to the named unit and replace them with references to its replacement.

In this case the [EurekaLog KB article](https://support.eurekalog.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/50/9/7x-i-get-error-about-exceptionlog-unit-being-deprecated) that is the first hit on a web search for your error message gives all the details:

> **Problem:**
>
> I get "Unit 'ExceptionLog' is deprecated" error when compiling my
>   application. However, when I try to remove this unit - I get many
>   "undeclared identificator" errors.
>
> **Reason:**
>
> ExceptionLog unit is unit from EurekaLog 6. It's included in EurekaLog
>   7 to import old EurekaLog 6 applications. However, it was marked as
>   "deprecated" to indicate that your application uses old code (i.e.
>   code from EurekaLog 6).
>
> EurekaLog 7 uses ExceptionLog7 unit instead (and additional units -
>   see below).
>
> **Solution:**
>
> Please note that this message is not error. Your application will be
>   compiled and run. It will function properly. This message is a
>   warning. A warning that notify you that your project uses old code.
>
> It's perfectly fine to use ExceptionLog unit in your application. If
>   you have old EurekaLog project and then you upgrade EurekaLog to
>   version 7 and import your project - it will be imported in
>   compatibility mode and ExceptionLog unit will be used. Now you can
>   recompile your application and it should work as before. Almost no
>   code change is required.
>
> If you don't want to see warnings about unit being deprecated - you
>   can either turn off these notification in project options or use $WARN
>   UNIT_DEPRECATED ON/OFF directives to selectably turn these warnings
>   messages on/off for parts of your code.
>
> However, if you want to upgrade your code, then you must disable
>   compatiblity mode and replace ExceptionLog references with references
>   to ExceptionLog7 unit. Also, when you start a new project - then you
>   will use new units by default (since there is no already written
>   code).
>
> Note that EurekaLog 7 is a major re-design of EurekaLog 6. EurekaLog 6
>   contains almost everything in one single unit (ExceptionLog), while
>   EurekaLog 7 split code into several units (such as ECallStack,
>   EModules, ESysInfo, EExceptionManager, EDebugInfo, ESend, EDialog,
>   etc.). That's why you may need to additionally include other units to
>   your uses clause. If you get "undeclared identificator" error - then
>   some unit is missing from uses. You can run a file search in \Source
>   folder of EurekaLog installation for *.pas files containing your
>   missed identificator (this will work also for editions without full
>   source code, as they contain headers). Alternatively, you may study
>   changes in EurekaLog 7.

Comment: I hope that you get the subliminal message contained in my second paragraph.